# request в классе django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

```
class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = "/accounts/login/"
    template_name = "registration/register.html"
    def form_valid(self, request, form):
        if request.POST['captcha'].lower() != request.session['captcha_secret']:
            return HttpResponseNotFound('wrong captcha')
        form.save()
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Мне нужно получить по POST captcha и сравнить с сгенерированной каптчой на правильность.
выводит ошибку `TypeError: form_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'`
как решить? заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зачем вы передаёте request? Попробуйте просто def form_valid(self,form)

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L55